# Как установить новую Windows, сохранив старую и использовать со старой?

Tags: windows, установка, hdd, ssd

Я хочу установить Windows 10 LTSC, у меня уже есть образ, купил SSD для него, но при этом хочу сохранить и нынешнюю винду на всякий случай. Но диск на котором у меня сейчас установлена винда, я хочу тоже использовать после установления новой, так как там терабайт памяти. Можно ли как-то сохранить старую винду, например на часть от диска, а другую часть после установки LTSC использовать, как хранилище файлов и другого?

Comment: Если у вас отдельный SSD под новую винду, то, например, просто временно отключите старый диск и установите винду на SSD, чтоб не путаться между дисками. После установки подключите старый диск обратно. Выбирать, с какого диска загружать систему, можно будет через биос

Comment: Лично мне в голову приходит только вариант разбить диск и установить на второй его раздел вторую Windows